# Default value of dynamic array argument in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

According to SystemVerilog LRM 3.1a (p.38) it is possible to pass dynamic array as an argument to tasks of functions:

```
 task foo( string arr[] );
```

Is it possible to assign a default value (zero-sized array) to this argument? Somewhat like we can do with other arguments:

```
task foo2(int i = -1, byte z = 0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found an answer. It is possible to do C-like array init at declaration time. Looks like:

```
task foo ( byte bar[] = '{} );
```

By the way, it seems there is no mentions about this possibility in LRM.

Comment: The 3.1a LRM is really old and out of date. Take a look at the latest which is publicly available. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399064/how-do-i-get-the-verilog-language-standard/16400635#16400635

Comment: Out of date compared to the SystemVerilog implementations that are out there?  My impressions is that the LRM leads the implementations by a long ways and using an older LRM might actually represent what your tools are doing more accurately.